# Run arduino project from winforms project within the same solution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, arduino

i have made a solution in visual studio in that, one i am having a project of winform application and another project of arduino. In my winform i have added a button. So i want that whenever i click button in winform the arduino code executes. please tell me the procedureto do so.

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be to send a message to the Arduino via the serial port.

Comment: Can you guide me as i am new to arduino or could you provide me a link from where  i can refer. And thank you for your reply Sir.

Answer (score 1):

A most simple command structure would be a single char. On the C# side, open a serial port and write the char:

```
// In the button handler write the command to the port
// Change port # to whatever
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
serialPort.Open();
serialPort.Write("1");
serialPort.Close();
```

And on the Arduino side:

```
void setup () 
{ 
    // Enable serial port
    Serial.begin(9600); 
} 

char cmd;
void loop () 
{ 
    if (Serial.available()) {
        // Read byte from serial port 
        cmd = Serial.read(); 
        switch (cmd) { 
            case '1':
            // Command from PC rcvd - do something here
            break; 
        }
    } 
}
```